# parsing MonthDate string in a leap year

Tags: java

please consider the following snippet:

```
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");
    parser.setLenient(false);
    try {
        Date date = parser.parse("0229");
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have a text field which should contain a date in the format MMdd (no year, as it should always default to the current year).

This year, 2012, a leap year, I found myself in the strange situation of not being able to parse the valid date February 29th.

The calendar used by the code above always defaults to 1970, which, though luck, was not a leap year. Hence trying to parse "0229" always throws a parse exception.

Any idea on how to parse this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append the current year and use a format of "MMddyyyy"?

Comment: Of course the logical way is to prepend, not append :) +1 though

Comment: Makes no difference if it's only for this purpose and the format is explicitly supplied. In normal usage though, I agree, MMddyyyy is pretty useless.

Comment: In the end I'll do it like this, but I would prefer to be format independent in my parser. What if the format is MMddHH, or MM'yyyy'dd and so on?

Comment: But it's not format independent at the moment - you've specified the format in the code? Am I missing something?

Comment: My fault, I simplyfied the story too much. The textfieds (and other UI components) are dynamically generated and validated based on formats coming from some xmls, which can change over time. That's why I'm trying to be as generic as possible.

Comment: OK, understood. How about if the format from the XML doesn't include the year, then append yyyy to it and append the current year?

Comment: This is the way I solved it (for now, as I don't want to invest more time in it), but this makes it difficult to know whether the year is in the format string or not. The doc says it can be y, yy, yyy or yyyy, and also you can have escaped characters in the format, as in my previous example MM'yyyy'dd, so what should have been five lines of code becomes one hundred.

Comment: Realised you've shelved this for now, but a thought - format 1/1/2011 and 1/1/2012 using the format string - if the result is different, the format string contains the year. Avoids parsing.